# ruby on rails: radio buttons for collection select

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I have a collection select:

```
  <%= f.collection_select :role, User::ROLES, :to_s, :humanize %>
```

What is the radio button for this method?

Thanks

Comment: Just use https://github.com/justinfrench/formtastic

Answer (score 7):

There is no such helper in Rails 3. In Rails 4, it is [collection_radio_buttons](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormBuilder.html#method-i-collection_radio_buttons).

Comment: is there an alternative?

Comment: I don't know any alternative. It is not difficult to generate the check boxes with a loop, as Rajarshi Das said.

Answer (score 2):

This way..

```
<%= f.collection_radio_buttons :role, User::ROLES  %>
```

Comment: in rails 4 there is this method  for rails 3 you have to run a loop of USER::ROLES.EACH do and in that loop you have to call <%= f.radio_button :role %=>

Answer (score 1):

No documentation found for the form builder, but this should work:

```
<%= f.collection_radio_buttons :my_attribute, my_hash.map {|k,v| [k,v]}, :first, :last do |b| %>
  <div class='my-class'>
    <%= b.radio_button %>
    <%= b.label %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```