# How do i add radio button and set their range from 1 to 5

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

How do i add range 1..5 in radio button. any help is much appreciated.

```
<%= f.radio_button :rating ,:class => "form-control" %>
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/18526150/532252

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do the job.

```
<%= f.collection_radio_buttons :rating, (1..5).map{|n| [n, n]}, :first, :last, :class => "form-control"" %>
```